# Remove AppUserLogins by item

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I have a custom AppUserStore. I have an issue when I want to remove a login for a user. For example, the user can use linked in or google to sign in.
Now, if he wants to remove one of these external logins, they are all removed.

Below the code used:

```
    Task IUserLoginStore<AppUser, int>.RemoveLoginAsync(AppUser user, UserLoginInfo login)
    {
        AppUserLogin externalLogin = DataContext.Entry<AppUser>(user).Entity.AppUserLogins
            .FirstOrDefault(l => l.LoginProvider == login.LoginProvider && l.ProviderKey == login.ProviderKey);

        if (externalLogin != null)
        {
            DataContext.Entry<AppUser>(user).Entity.AppUserLogins.Remove(externalLogin);
        }
        return DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

I have a problem with this line:
DataContext.Entry(user).Entity.AppUserLogins.Remove(externalLogin);

I don't understand why all the **AppUserLogins** are removed.

Comment: Have you checked if external login is really does have the value you looking for ?

Comment: I believe you must override the `Equals` method in the class `LoginInfo` and specifiy how a `LoginInfo` is equal to another

Answer (score 0):

Okay I find why I had this issue. It's because the id for all AppUserLogins was 0. It's because in the database I only have 3 columns: UserId, LoginProvider and ProviderKey.

So when I did is override the property Id

```
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return (UserId.ToString() + LoginProvider + ProviderKey).GetHashCode(); }
        set { Id = (UserId.ToString() + LoginProvider + ProviderKey).GetHashCode(); }
    }
```

Now, every AppUserLogins has an unique Id and I can remove them by item.